# Pass docker-compose environment to symfony configuration

Tags: symfony, docker, environment-variables

I want to pass configuration parameters from docker-compose file to my Symfony application, I tried this:

```
app:
    image: <NGINX + PHP-FPM IMAGE>
    environment:
        DATABASE_HOST: db
```

My parameters.yml file :

```
database_host: "%env(DATABASE_HOST)%"
```

I get error 500 "Environment variable not found: DATABASE_HOST"

I also tried SYMFONY__DATABASE_HOST in docker-compose but also not working.

How does it work?

Comment: `DATABASE_HOST=db`

Comment: Configuration looks totally valid. Do you see environment variable set with `docker inspect <container>`?

Comment: @johnharris85 if he's using Docker Compose version 3 or 2 both `DATABASE_HOST: db` and `- DATABASE_HOST=db` are valid according to the documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#environment)

Comment: So they are! Thanks :)

Comment: Hello, were you able to make this work? I did the same thing. I can see my env variables when I type 'docker inspect' and also inside the container when I type 'env'. However, when I set "%env(DATABASE_USER)%" on the parameters.yml Symfony is not able to find it.

Answer (score 3):

The error you're receiving refers to Symfony runtime environment variables [(see here)](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-runtime-environment-variables). Docker compose environment variables are retrieved from the `.env` file that resides within the build context (AKA the directory where you want **docker-compose** to run from) of the `docker-compose.yml` file. What you really want to do is make sure that the environment variables you set in your Symfony config/parameters and your `docker-compose.yml` file match, *especially the db host*.

You should consider breaking your image up into PHP-FPM and Nginx images to have better potential scalability and a separation of concerns according to the best practices outlined by Docker [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#each-container-should-have-only-one-concern). All of these technologies have regularly-maintained images available on [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/).

Here's my `docker-compose.yml` that creates containers for PHP-FPM, MySQL, and Nginx in a multicontainer environment with the latest stable packages available as of today.

```
version: '3'

services:
    db:
        image: mysql
        volumes:
            - ./.data/db:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
            MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    php:
        build: php7.1-fpm
        depends_on:
            - db
        ports:
            - "9000:9000"
        volumes:
            - symfony-bind-mount:/var/www/symfony
            - symfony-logs-bind-mount:/var/www/symfony/app/logs
    nginx:
        build: nginx
        depends_on:
            - php
        ports:
            - "8025:8025"
            - "80:80"
        volumes:
            - symfony-bind-mount:/var/www/symfony
            - nginx-logs-bind-mount:/var/log/nginx

volumes:
    symfony-bind-mount:
        driver: local
        driver_opts:
            o: bind,rw
            type: none
            device: ${SYMFONY_APP_PATH}
    nginx-logs-bind-mount:
        driver: local
        driver_opts:
            o: bind,rw
            type: none
            device: ${DOCKER_SYMFONY_PATH}/logs/nginx
    symfony-logs-bind-mount:
        driver: local
        driver_opts:
            o: bind,rw
            type: none
            device: ${DOCKER_SYMFONY_PATH}/logs/symfony
```

Here's my .env file:

```
# Symfony application's path
SYMFONY_APP_PATH=/absolute/path/to/symfony/project

# Path to local docker-symfony repository
DOCKER_SYMFONY_PATH=/absolute/path/to/sibling/docker/directory

# MySQL
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
MYSQL_DATABASE=mydb
MYSQL_USER=
MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
```

You can checkout my fork of maxpou's docker-symfony repository [here](https://github.com/celowsky/docker-symfony). I've updated the docker-compose.yml and the bind mounts to be compatible with version 3 of the Compose file format.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you're right about the .env file, It works with it. But I think it's too much for my need because Symfony reads .env file on each request, on production not good for performance. Is there a way to "build" parameters.yml with docker-compose environment variables?

Also thanks on the advice about my compose file, the thing is I build and push my application on my own private registry. I use one image with PHP-FPM + NGINX + CODE SOURCE. I don't know how to manage this with multiple containers.